# composer update error

Tags: php, symfony

While updating composer I get the following error. I have read another similar question which suggested setting up date.timezone for php. I have done that but error wasnt removed. What should I do?

Error:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]  
  Unrecognized option "role_heirarchy" under "security"                          


Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:  


    [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurati        
  onException]                                                               
    Unrecognized option "role_heirarchy" under "security"
```

Comment: Have you install fosuserbundle using composer? composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle

Comment: So exists : vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOSUserBundle.php ?

Comment: `composer show -i | grep friendsofsymfony`, does that show the FOSUserBundle package?